# Why does the union of all open null sets is itself a nullset for second countable space?

Tags: measure-theory

On the online Encyclopedia of mathematics, it is written  "The existence of a countable base guarantees that the union of all open μ-null sets is itself a nullset."
See: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Support_of_a_measure

I do not understand this result, i.e., I do not manage to prove it. I think that I have a sketch of a proof, but I have not been able to complete it. See below. Any proof/explanation is welcome.

Let $(X,\mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a second countable measure space, and $\mathcal{O}:=\bigcup\{O \subset X: O  \text{ open and }\mu(O)=0\} $. $\mathcal{O}$ is an open set as a union of open sets. Thus, by second countability of $X$, $\mathcal{O} $ can be written as a countable union of open sets extracted from a countable base of $X$, i.e.,   $\mathcal{O}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbf{N}} O_{\alpha(n)}$, where $\alpha: \mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N} $ is an increasing function, and $\{O_n\}_{n \in \mathbf{N}} $ is a base of $X$. Therefore, by $\sigma$-additivity of measures, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu(\mathcal{O})=\mu(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbf{N}} O_{\alpha(n)})\leqslant \sum_{n \in \mathbf{N}}\mu(O_{\alpha(n)})
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, to conclude $\mu(\mathcal{O})=0 $, I would probably like to say that, for all  $n \in \mathbf{N} $, $\mu(O_{\alpha(n)}) =0$. But I do not see why it should be the case...

**Answer by David Mitra** (as far as I understand it): Index the set of open null sets  by $i \in I $, i.e., define $I$ s.t. $\{U_i \}_{i \in I}:=\{O \subset X: O  \text{ open and }\mu(O)=0\} $. By second countability, for all $i \in I $, $U_i=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbf{N}}  O_{\alpha_i(n)}$ where $\alpha_i: \mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N} $ is an increasing function, and $\{O_n\}_{n \in \mathbf{N}} $ is a base of $X$.  Now, note that by monotonicity of measures,  for all $i \in I $, and $n \in \mathbf{N} $, $\mu(O_{\alpha_i(n)})\leqslant \mu(U_i)=0 $, which implies that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(O_{\alpha_i(n)})=0 \qquad (1)
\end{eqnarray}
Moreover, the union of all open null sets can be expressed as
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{O} &= &\bigcup_{i \in I}U_i=\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcup_{n\in\mathbf{N}}O_{\alpha_i(n)}\\
& = &\bigcup_{m \in \mathbf{N}} O_{\beta(m)}
\end{eqnarray}
where for all $m \in \mathbf{N} $, there exits $n \in \mathbf{N} $ and $i \in I $ s.t. $\beta(m)=\alpha_i(n) $. Then, using (1), the completion of the proof above follows 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu(\mathcal{O})=\mu(\bigcup_{m\in \mathbf{N}} O_{\beta(m)})\leqslant \sum_{m \in \mathbf{N}}\mu(O_{\beta(m)})=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Thanks David Mitra!

Comment: Express each of the open sets as a countable union of members of your base. Then you'll have that these members are null sets.

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove and then use that every open cover $(U_i)_i$ of $W =\bigcup_i U_i$ in a second countable space admits a countable subcover $(U_{i_n})_n$ of $W$.